# In android application, Whats the usage of giving coreApp="true" in android Manifest file ? and why its not required before Honey Comb?

Tags: android, performance, android-manifest

In android application, Whats the usage of giving coreApp="true" in android Manifest file?
And why its not required before Honey Comb?
How it helps in improving the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Add boot mode where only "core apps" are started.

A core app is one that has coreApp="true" in its manifest tag.

Comment: I got it .. whats the performance impact of making an app as CoreApp and also this feature is available only after honeycomb. how its handled before that ?

Comment: no need to implement this because in before honeycomb only one apk is releas now 2 apk release  one for test 2nd for release version ( after set licence )